# Full Join in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe looking like:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~sub_date, ~period,
        "2019-01",       1,
        "2019-01",       2,
        "2019-01",       3,
        "2019-02",       1,
        "2019-02",       2,
        "2019-03",       1,
        "2019-03",       2,
        "2019-03",       3,
        "2019-03",       4
        )

  sub_date period
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 2019-01       1
2 2019-01       2
3 2019-01       3
4 2019-02       1
5 2019-02       2
6 2019-03       1
7 2019-03       2
8 2019-03       3
9 2019-03       4
```

and another:

```
period <- tibble::tribble(
            ~period, ~forecast,
                  1,        10,
                  2,        20,
                  3,        30,
                  4,        40,
                  5,        50,
                  6,        60,
                  7,        70
            )


  period forecast
   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1       10
2      2       20
3      3       30
4      4       40
5      5       50
6      6       60
7      7       70
```

I am struggling to join them in a way that in `df` I can fill the missing periods in the table `period`, aka the number of rows in `period` X the different sub_date in `df`.

as follows:

```
df_output <- tibble::tribble(
               ~sub_date, ~period, ~forecast,
               "2019-01",       1,        10,
               "2019-01",       2,        20,
               "2019-01",       3,        30,
               "2019-01",       4,        40,
               "2019-01",       5,        50,
               "2019-01",       6,        60,
               "2019-01",       7,        70,
               "2019-02",       1,        10,
               "2019-02",       2,        20,
               "2019-02",       3,        30,
               "2019-02",       4,        40,
               "2019-02",       5,        50,
               "2019-02",       6,        60,
               "2019-02",       7,        70,
               "2019-03",       1,        10,
               "2019-03",       2,        20,
               "2019-03",       3,        30,
               "2019-03",       4,        40,
               "2019-03",       5,        50,
               "2019-03",       6,        60,
               "2019-03",       7,        70
               )

# A tibble: 21 x 3
   sub_date period forecast
   <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2019-01       1       10
 2 2019-01       2       20
 3 2019-01       3       30
 4 2019-01       4       40
 5 2019-01       5       50
 6 2019-01       6       60
 7 2019-01       7       70
 8 2019-02       1       10
 9 2019-02       2       20
10 2019-02       3       30
# … with 11 more rows
```

I assumed it was a full join but I don't get the desired result.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `tidyr::crossing` to obtained your desired result:

```
crossing(select(df, sub_date), period)
```

Note that you are not looking for a `join` since you want every combination of `sub_date` combinded (or crossed) with every combination of `period` and `forecast`.

Comment: why do you use `select`? does `crossing` work in the case of `df` having multiple columns? @Cettt

Comment: Try `crossing(distinct(df, sub_date), df)` instead.

Comment: @xxxvincxxx, if you do it with multiple columns, you run into a collision (`Error: Column name `period` must not be duplicated.`), try and see. In this case, the other columns in `df` are perhaps a red herring in that it looks like `df$period` should be matched/joined with `period$period`, but ... the output does not suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to merge the tables? Try this to see if it gives you what you need?

`df <- df %>% distinct(sub_date)
answer <- merge(periods, df, all = TRUE)`